# minimise function with constraints on non-optimisation variables

Tags: python, optimization

I need to optimise a function with a constraint on a variable which is calculated by solving a set of equations.

The optimisation parameters are the input variables to the system of equations and one of the calculated variables have a constraint.

Here is an extremely simplified example:

```
def opt(x):
    x1, x2, x3 = x

    z1 = x1 + x2 + x3
    z2 = z1**2
    .
    .
    .
    z100 = f(x1, x2, x3, z1, ..., z99)

    return some objective function
```

minimise opt(x)
s.t. z100 < a

I am familiar with `scipy.optimize.minimize` but I can not set a constraint on `z100` and it is extremely difficult to calculate a function for `z100` with only the variables `x1, x2, x3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad, but some remarks:

- `and it is extremely difficult to calculate a function for z100 with only the variables x1, x2, x3`

  - Where is the problem? Just use the [args-argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) inside the call to minimize and you can use all the objects you want
- `I am familiar with scipy.optimize.minimize but I can not set a constraint on z100`

  - This somewhat implicates, that `z100` is depending on the optimization-variables (which makes it a constraint on optimization-variables opposed to the title; or there is no effect / reason to use it at all as we are only modifying opt-vars and no a-priori constraint-logic is affected)
  - Just introduce an auxiliary-variable `y0` and constraints:

    - `y0 < a`
    - `y0 == f(...)`
    - **But:** this might contradict the solver's assumptions about smoothness (depending on f of course). So you probably should think again about your problem (and for us there is nothing to do as the structure of that problem is not posted)
    - **And:** eq-constraints sometimes are a bit of a hassle in regards to numerical-trouble